# MySQL query not returning any results even though data exists in database

Tags: php, mysql

Why is this query not showing more than one data. Even I have 10/12 data but this line only shows 1. Check I have limited it to 3 but it only shows 1.

```
$getAds = mysql_query("SELECT * 
     FROM advertises 
     WHERE status='RUNNING' 
     AND adult='0' 
     AND (country LIKE '%$test%' OR country='ALL') 
     AND (device LIKE '%$pabu%' OR device='ALL') 
     ORDER BY rand() 
     LIMIT 0,3");
```

my database structure

Table structure for table `advertises` --

```
CREATE TABLE `advertises` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `userid` int(11) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(5000) NOT NULL, `url` varchar(5000) NOT NULL, `type` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `device` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `country` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `time` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `status` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `dset` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `cset` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `acpc` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `ucpc` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `adult` tinyint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `title` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `pcpc` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `spent` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `adc` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

------ -- -- Dumping data for table `advertises` --

```
INSERT INTO `advertises` VALUES ('1','1','dqui.com/adultb.php','lt.adqui.com','banner','ALL','ALL','Saturday , September 19 , 2015','RUNNING','no','no','0.015','0.012','1','Android Adult','0.005','49999.925',''); INSERT INTO `advertises` VALUES ('2','1','http://adqui.com/banner.php','http://kid.adqui.com','banner','ALL','ALL','Saturday , September 19 , 2015','RUNNING','no','no','0.01','0.008','0','Android Non','0.002','49999.88',''); 

INSERT INTO `advertises` VALUES ('3','1','qui.com/adultb.php','lt.adqui.com','banner','ALL','ALL','Saturday , September 19 , 2015','RUNNING','no','no','0.0002','0.0002','1','Adult','0.00','4999.874','0.0002'); INSERT INTO `advertises` VALUES ('4','1','adqu i.com/banner.php','kid.adq ui.com','banner','ALL','ALL','Saturday , September 19 , 2015','RUNNING','no','no','0.0002','0.002','0','non','','4999.923','0.0008');
```

Comment: Are you sure, you have more data which matches to these condition?

Comment: yes I am sure. I store over 40 data

Comment: \Why can't you remove your conditions and run the quest manually on phpmyadmin and check you are getting more records

Comment: that also same result bro I don't think so its because condition

Comment: can you post your table structure and records

Comment: Provide your sample data

Answer (score 0):

Status is a keyword in mysql. so try this

```
$getAds=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM advertises WHERE `status`='RUNNING' AND adult='0' AND (country LIKE '%test%' OR country='ALL') AND (device LIKE '%pabu%' OR device='ALL') ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,3");
```

Comment: please provide your mysql table structure with sample data

Comment: I am newbie. whice type structure u need

Comment: mysql table and its column and datatype used.

Comment: -- Wap PhpMyAdmin 211 -- http://master-land.net/phpmyadmin -- Generation Time: 2016-01-06 05:24 -- MySQL Server Version: 5.5.47-MariaDB -- PHP Version: 5.4.45 -- Database: `adquicom_d` -- -------------------------------------------------------- -- -- Table structure for table `advertises` -- CREATE TABLE `advertises` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `userid` int(11) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(5000) NOT NULL, `url` varchar(5000) NOT NULL, `type` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `device` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `country` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `time` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `status` varchar(500) NOT NU

Comment: -- Wap PhpMyAdmin 211 -- http://master-land.net/phpmyadmin -- Generation Time: 2016-01-06 05:24 -- MySQL Server Version: 5.5.47-MariaDB -- PHP Version: 5.4.45 -- Database: `adquicom_d` -- -------------------------------------------------------- -- -- Table structure for table `advertises` -- CREATE TABLE `advertises` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `userid` int(11) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(5000) NOT NULL, `url` varchar(5000) NOT NULL, `type` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `device` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `country` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `time` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `status` varchar(500) NOT NU

Comment: Table structure for table `advertises` -- CREATE TABLE `advertises` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `userid` int(11) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(5000) NOT NULL, `url` varchar(5000) NOT NULL, `type` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `device` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `country` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `time` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `status` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `dset` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `cset` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `acpc` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `ucpc` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `adult` tinyint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `title` varchar(500) NOT NULL, `pcpc` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `sp

Comment: add it to your question. It will helps others also to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use mysql_fetch_assoc on the result returned by mysql_query?
Refer to the [mysql-query manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) in particular Example #2

Comment: then you need to do it cause result of ``mysql_query`` is not actual data from the query. Btw try to use PDO instead aswell cause ``mysql_*`` functions are deprecated.

Comment: any example for that bro

Comment: check the link that i provided in the answer and then see Example #2

Comment: @user5742387 you can find examples of PDO [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: but I need mysql instead of pdo

Comment: @user5742387 
 
check the link that i provided in the answer and then see Example #2 **it is for mysql_query**

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` has already been deprecated, you can use PDO instead.

Try below,

```
<?php
    $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'root', '');

    $test = 'All';
    $pabu = 'All';
    $qry = "SELECT * 
     FROM advertises 
     WHERE status='RUNNING' 
     AND adult='0' 
     AND (country LIKE '%$test%' OR country='ALL') 
     AND (device LIKE '%$pabu%' OR device='ALL') 
     ORDER BY rand() 
     LIMIT 0,3";

     $rq = $dbcon->query($qry);
     $op = ( $rq ) ? $rq->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) : '';
     echo '<pre>'; print_r($op);
?>
```

Comment: I have 0 idea on pdo